# Error library not loaded after installing php7.2

Tags: php, terminal, homebrew

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/tidy-html5/lib/libtidy.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
```

The library is already installed and it's visible in `Cellar/`, however, when trying to run anything with php, returns that error. If
I try to manually link, says that it's already linked.:
"brew link tidy-html5

```
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/tidy-html5/5.8.0
To relink, run:
  brew unlink tidy-html5 && brew link tidy-html5"
```

No idea what to do, already tried reinstalling everything.. the php, the library, the node, everything...

Comment: Compare the paths. You could create a link.

Comment: The issue is with php@7.2, can you `brew reinstall php@7.2`?